# Finding bijection between all Equivalence classes and sets of prime numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

$R$ relation $aRb \leftrightarrow  a/b = q^2$ where $q$ is in $Q$.
We need a bijection $X→Y$ where $X$ is the set of all Equivalence classes and $Y$ is the set of all sets $P$ that consists only of prime numbers and $|P|$ is not infinity. For example, an element $P$ of $Y$ is $\{2,3,5\}$.

I am stuck here.  I have found the equivalent classes but I can't seem to find a bijection here. Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: I'll repeat the hint I gave the first time you posted this:  show that each equivalence class contains exactly one squarefree integer

Comment: Note:  I expect you want $a,b \in \mathbb Q^*$, else you have troubles such as $0\sim 1$ but $1\not\sim 0$.

Comment: what does  squarefree integer means ?

Comment: A square free integer is one that is not divisible by the square of any prime.  Thus $2,3,5$ are square free as are $6,15,21$ but $12$ is not as it is divisible by $4=2^2$.

Comment: Note:  since any squarefree integer can be factored as a product of distinct primes there is an obvious bijection between the set of squarefree integers and your set $Y$ namely $p_1p_2\cdots p_n\leftrightarrow (p_1,p_2,\cdots,p_n)$.